# Delphi XE2 modern looking MainMenu

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am trying to modernize the look of our older Delphi 7 application now that we are using Delphi XE-2.  I experimented with the TRibbon, and although I like it, it probably is not the correct solution since we currently use a TMainMenu and make many runtime changes to it - our users can modify the main menu. But the default Mainmenu looks old, especially compared to the image shown.

What I am trying to do is something very close to the attached image, especially with the background color, but I don't quite understand how this was done.  Can anyone tell me if this example (the File/View/Insert section) uses a TMainMenu, or is it Buttons on a Toolbar ?  If we require a customizable main menu, do you think the example shown is an option ?

This example image comes from DevExpress Print Sample library.

Edit : I am new here so I can't include the image. Here is the link :

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExPrintingSystem/gallery.xml

The second image, the green one that says "Print Preview".

Comment: OK, I may have found it, that may be a TActionToolbar, possibly on top of another toolbar.  I have not worked with Actions before, maybe it's time to learn.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the TActionMainMenuBar but the simpler solution for you is to Use Vcl styles, pick a theme, modify the graphical properties of a MainMenu component and then use StyleHooks to force the style just for the MainMenu component without using it for the whole application.